# Associate a checkbox with an input field and make it mandatory only if input value exists

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a manual verification system and want the user to check each `checkbox` associated with individual inputs if a value exists before submission else the form would throw an error.

I have implemented this, but it does not seem to work. Also, I was wondering if there was a better way of achieving the same wherein we avoid passing the parameters to the function.

Similar to how we can associate a submit button for a form using `form` by supplying the `id`.

```
<form>

    <input type="text" name="inputFieldOne">
    <input type="checkbox" onblur="makeSureItIsSelected('inputFieldOne', 'inputCheckboxOne')" name="inputCheckboxOne">

    <input type="text" name="inputFieldTwo">
    <input type="checkbox" onblur="makeSureItIsSelected('inputFieldTwo', 'inputCheckboxTwo')" name="inputCheckboxTwo">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<script>

    function makeSureItIsSelected(field, checkbox){
        let fieldBox = document.getElementsByName(field)[0];
        if(fieldBox.value != ''){
            checkBox = document.getElementsByName(checkbox)[0];
            checkBox.required = true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, will edit it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I want the user to check it manually.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I am parsing a `PDF` and trying to fill values based on how the parse value comes out. This is to check the values as a way of perfecting the values which don't so as to help in training it better.

Comment: Will fix the declaration. Thanks.

Comment: The field is getting populated from an `API` which takes in a `PDF` as input and returns a `JSON`. The `JSON` contains fields which are used to populate the inputs. The checkbox is to make sure that the value from the `API` is getting generated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the checkbox to be required when the field has a value, you should hook an event on the *field*, not the checkbox. `input` would make a good event for this:

```js
function makeSureItIsSelected(field, checkbox){
    let fieldBox = document.getElementsByName(field)[0];
    let checkBox = document.getElementsByName(checkbox)[0];
    // Require the checkbox when the field has a value
    checkBox.required = fieldBox.value != '';
}
```

```html
<form>

    <input type="text" name="inputFieldOne" oninput="makeSureItIsSelected('inputFieldOne', 'inputCheckboxOne')">
    <input type="checkbox" name="inputCheckboxOne">

    <input type="text" name="inputFieldTwo" oninput="makeSureItIsSelected('inputFieldTwo', 'inputCheckboxTwo')">
    <input type="checkbox" name="inputCheckboxTwo">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Note that there's no need for those calls to `getElementsByName`: Just pass `this` into the function, and use `nextElementSibling` to access the checkbox:

```js
function makeSureItIsSelected(field){
    // Require the checkbox when the field has a value
    field.nextElementSibling.required = field.value != '';
}
```

```html
<form>

    <input type="text" name="inputFieldOne" oninput="makeSureItIsSelected(this)">
    <input type="checkbox" name="inputCheckboxOne">

    <input type="text" name="inputFieldTwo" oninput="makeSureItIsSelected(this)">
    <input type="checkbox" name="inputCheckboxTwo">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

---

That said, it seems odd to have the checkboxes at all. The presence of the field in the form data should be sufficient. But if the checkbox's value **has** to be in the form data, simply add it on submit without having a checkbox at all.

Comment: Thank you for the snippet, It is what I'll be using.